PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx getSheetByName not working
I hate posting this because I feel like this should be simple, but I have investigated and tested many things. My script has been working fine if I want the first sheet to be read. Again, that works fine. BUT, I want to be able to specify a specific sheet to be read instead of the ActiveSheet (first sheet).
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx;  
           $reader = new Xlsx(); 
           $spreadsheet = $reader->load($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); 
           //$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();  //works using this
      
           // this is where it fails
           $worksheetName="test";
           $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getSheetByName($worksheetName); 
           $worksheet_arr = $worksheet->toArray(); 

Error is:
  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function toArray() on null in 
  import.php:28 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in 
  import.php on line 28

  Line 28: $worksheet_arr = $worksheet->toArray(); 

Any help is much appreciated!

GHOSTS I tell you! I came into the office this morning and ran the exact code I mentioned above to specify a specific tab AND IT WORKED! So frustrating. I'd delete this Question but instead I will keep it here in case someone else runs into this issue. My suggestion would be to ward off any spirits and come back the next day.
